# Could not start more threads despite using Executors

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executor

i have been advised to use `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` which will be able to solve problems when over-spawning threads.

However there is still an error when the number of threads is growing past a certain point. Is there anyway to allow a thread to wait itself while waiting for system resources to be available?

```
[WARN ] Thread table can't grow past 16383 threads.

[ERROR][thread ] Could not start thread pool-1-thread-16114. errorcode -1
Exception in thread "Main Thread" java.lang.Error: errorcode -1
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:640)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addIfUnderMaximumPoolSize(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:727)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:657)
    at sg.java.executors_helloworld.App.main(App.java:15)

public class App {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            es.execute(new Car());
        }

        long completedIn = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;

        System.out.println(DurationFormatUtils.formatDuration(completedIn,
                "HH:mm:ss:SS"));
    }
}



public class Car implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Car <" + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                + "> doing something");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Each thread uses stack space, when you run out of stack space you cannot create more threads. The cached pool will create a thread for every task but unless you lots of tasks that spend all their time waiting, i.e. not using CPU, you are better off limiting the number of threads to something closer to some multiple of the number of cores you have. e.g. 4,8,16.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `newCachedThreadPool`:

> Creates a thread pool that creates new threads as needed,  but will reuse previously constructed threads when they are available.

It sounds like you want a pool with a maximum size. For example:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);
```

That will use at most 50 threads at a time. (50 may well not be the right number for you, of course - it depends what you're doing.)

Comment: It is worth noting that this will use 50 threads, no more and no less. It is actually quite difficult to get a pool in the current standard lib that has a core size lower than the max.