# ThreadPool stuck in awaitTermination due to OutOfMemory

Tags: java, out-of-memory, threadpool

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);
try {
   try {
      for (Worker workerItem: workers) {
        executor.execute(workerItem);
      }
   } finally {
         executor.shutdown();
         executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
   }
} catch (Throwable) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Follwing code structure reflects real code. We suffered from a severe problem i n producton - we had a spike that caused OutofMemoryError. System recovered some time after.

```
[memory ][Wed Feb 22 20:53:03 2017][23193] [OC#2194] 432865.981-432866.802: OC 8023932KB->899782KB (8388608KB), 0.821 s, sum of pauses 515.616 ms, longest pause 515.616 ms.
[thread ][Wed Feb 22 20:53:06 2017][23193] Could not start thread CCBSubmitPool-Thread13753. Resource temporarily unavailable
[memory ][Wed Feb 22 20:53:06 2017][23193] Throwing OutOfMemory: Resource temporarily unavailable in tsStartJavaThread (lifecycle.c:1097).
```

The problem is that there were like 50 workers scheduled, but the third one failed to start. In a result, threadpool got stuck in awaitTermination. This is an ultra crucial part of the application. The idea is to detect such a state and perform certain action. Question is - is there a way to determine such state?

thanks

edit.
This example ([Could not start more threads despite using Executors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888029/could-not-start-more-threads-despite-using-executors)) perfectly shows the problem. 16382nd thread was rejected, threadpool waits in awaitTermination until timeout elapses.

Comment: I think workers size is exceeds than actual pool size. that why this error appears

Comment: Root cause of OOM is unknown. My pool is the victim no the cause.

Comment: how you are created Workers? can you post that code?

Comment: More or less like this for (WorktoDo work: workList) {
                Worker worker = new Worker();
               }